# WP7 PhotoChooserTask causes app to reload

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

After selecting a photo using the PhotoChooserTask my entire app seems to be reloading.  Anybody else seeing this problem or know if its just a debugging issue?

I was able to recreate this behavior in a simple app with one page, but where it really is apparent is in an MVVM project I'm working on when I see my entire ViewModelLocator class being recreated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you mean by reloading?

Maybe you mean that your app is tombstoning? This is a design pattern. More info about [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: At the end of the article Lukas linked you'll see PhotoChooserTask is one among a few tasks that *may* tombstone your app. It's suggested you handle this.

Comment: What I'm seeing is the Application class App.xml.cs constructor is firing when control returns from the PhotoChooserTask.  This is causing my ViewModelLocator class that is a static resource in App.xml to be created again.  It could be Tombstoning like you said. I see Application_Deativate fire but never Application_Closing.  Any ideas of how to handle this when using a ViewModelLocator that creates lots of ViewModels in its contructor?

Answer (score 0):

Start here: [understanding the windows phone application...](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx) Every time your screen is switched with another screen your application is terminated. It gets tombstoned when it's an 'intrusion' but could could dropped completely.